# graphql apollo fails to run script

Tags: swift, graphql

i followed the tutorial provided by apollo and each time i build to run the script that generate the api file ,i get the following massage:

```
iphonesimulator/Apollo/Apollo.framework/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

this is the project:https://github.com/mkamal13/graphqlapollo
can any body help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new versions it's called `run-bundled-codegen.sh`, change it in the script you added to `Build Phases`